# Azure Translator Text API v3.0 - Possible Error Codes

Tags: azure, error-code, microsoft-translator

I'm looking for all possible error codes of the Azure Translator Text API 3.0.

I just found one page that describes the format of an error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#errors

The example is an errorcode: 403000
I recieved another error code and now I need all possible error codes to handle it correctly in my application.

Someone know how to figure out all the possible error codes?
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

There's a table of response codes under each of the api's. e.g for Translate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate?tabs=curl

> Response status codes
>
> The following are the possible HTTP status codes that a request
>   returns.
>
> Status Code   Description
>
> - 200    Success.
> - 400    One of the query parameters is missing or not valid. Correct    request parameters before retrying.
> - 401    The request could not be authenticated. Check that credentials    are specified and valid.
> - 403    The request is not authorized. Check the details error message.    This often indicates that all free translations provided with a trial 
>     subscription have been used up.
> - 429    The caller is sending too many requests.
> - 500    An unexpected error occurred. If the error persists, report it    with: date and time of the failure, request identifier from response
>     header X-RequestId, and client identifier from request header
>     X-ClientTraceId.
> - 503    Server temporarily unavailable. Retry the request. If the error    persists, report it with: date and time of the failure, request
>     identifier from response header X-RequestId, and client identifier
>     from request header X-ClientTraceId.

Comment: I didn't talk about "HTTP status codes". I'm looking for the error codes within an response message like 

{
  "error": {
    "code":403000,
    "message":"The subscription has exceeded its free quota."
    }
}

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#errors

Answer (score 0):

For each method (translate, dictionary lookup, etc) you can find the error codes in the Response Status Codes section, For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate?tabs=curl#response-status-codes

Comment: I didn't talk about "HTTP status codes". I'm looking for the error codes within an response message like 

{
  "error": {
    "code":403000,
    "message":"The subscription has exceeded its free quota."
    }
}

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#errors

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do not have more granular codes documented and will take this request to do so. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Oh - I didn't expect that answer. Is the Translator-API released recently?
How can I use an API without handling all possible errors?

Someone there who is using this API? Is it usable in an productive and scaleable application?

Comment: Hi @Microsoft Translator - you have any updates for us?

Comment: They have documented the error codes!

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#errors